# Do the proceeds I receive from realizing a capital loss increase my gross income?

Tags: united-states, capital-loss

Suppose that in 2017 I bought 100 shares of XYZ stock. Would selling all these shares in 2018 for $900 worth of proceeds at a cost basis of $1,000 (realizing a capital loss of $100) increase my 2018 gross income by $900? Does the answer change depending on whether the capital loss is a short-term or long-term capital loss?

Note: I'm asking about gross income, not adjusted gross income (AGI), because I want to know if my gross income is less than my filing threshold.

Comment: How on earth would one earn money from a loss?

Comment: @quid, by selling selling all 100 shares of XYZ stock, I'd get $900.

Comment: That's not an earning.

Comment: OK. Thank you, @quid. To improve the title of my question, I changed "Does the money I earn" to "Do the proceeds I get".

Comment: There is no income here; you converted one asset you already owned (stock) into another form (cash).

Comment: OK. Thank you @chepner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Gross income doesn't include proceeds received from realizing a capital loss, regardless of whether the capital loss is a short-term or long-term capital loss.

Gross income (as defined by [Section 61 of the Internal Revenue Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/61)) includes "gains derived from dealings in property", not proceeds. Also, gross income doesn't include capital losses. Chart A of the [2018 instructions for Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/i1040gi--2018.pdf) says "gross income includes gains, but not losses, reported on Form 8949 or Schedule D".

Comment: Small detail but the gross sales proceeds are included in Schedule D when determining the capital gain/loss.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, by "income for tax purposes" and by your other uses of the word "income", do you mean "gross income", as defined by [Section 61(a) of the Internal Revenue Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/61)?

Comment: @ma11hew28 Yes, since that section refers to "*Gains* derived from dealings in property", if a sale results in no gain there is no contribution to gross income.

Comment: OK. Thank you. So your saying that my gross income would go down by $100? I don't think that's right.

Comment: @ma11hew28 I _think_ it's more you have a gross income of `x`, and capital losses of `y` (=$100). Depending on the value of `x` (is it greater than zero, above certain thresholds, and probably other factors), the capital loss (probably up to certain limits) can be used to _offset_ the gross income you pay tax on.

Comment: @TripeHound, OK. Thank you. But my question is about gross income. Gross income doesn't include capital losses. I've edited this answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

> by selling selling all 100 shares of XYZ stock, I'd get $900.

By that logic, your 2017 income would have been reduced by $1000.

But that's not how it works.  Capital *gains* and *losses* are only *realized* when you sell the asset.